# Is it possible to round to an integer AND remove the decimal point in an array in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, rounding

After rounding to an integer the result of operations between lists that produce an array is there a way to remove the decimal point?   I am using python in Jupyter notebooks.

Should I use something other than 'np.round'?

'FoodSpent and 'Income' and are simply two lists of data that I created. The initial rounding attempt left the decimal point.

```
>>>PercentFood = np.around((FoodSpent / Income) * 100, 0)
>>>PercentFood

array([[ 10.,   7.,  11.,  10.,   6.,  10.,  10.,  12.,  11.,   9.,  11.,
         14.]
```

Thanks to advice given I ran the following, which rounded down to the integer without giving the decimal point.

```
>>> PercentFood = ((FoodSpent / Income) * 100)
>>> PercentFood.astype(int)

array([[ 9,  6, 11,  9,  6,  9, 10, 11, 10,  9, 11, 13]])
```

Comment: Cast each to an `integer`.  And fix your syntax.

Comment: How do I "cast each to an integer"?  Thanks

Comment: The decimal point indicates that the values are floating point.  Look at `PercentFood.dtype`.  `PercentFood.astype(int)` should cast your array to integer dtype.

Comment: Thanks...I tried `PercentFood.dtype`  in the input and received this error" 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'.     I also tried  `PercentFood.astype(int)` and it returned the same error message.   Any thoughts on that @hpaulj?

Comment: Then `PerentFood` is a list, not an array.  What you show is an array, but apparently you are applying my suggestion(s) to something else.

Comment: It is an array.  It seems that I had an error somewhere else in the program.  When I tried your suggestion again it worked. Thanks  @hpaulj

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how exactly your code works with this much context, but you can put this after rounding to get rid of the decimal.

PercentFood = [round(x) for x in PercentFood]

Comment: FoodSpent and Income are simply lists of 12 data points.   I tried `for x in PercentFood:
    np.round(x)`   and it did not clear the decimal.   For the code you suggested I received this error message:   This `type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method`

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know enough about numpy to provide further help. But I hope there is someone out there that does.

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested by the OP performs a floor operation (rounding "down" to the nearest integer). For more typical rounding use hpaulj's suggestion:

```py
import numpy as np

foo = [1.1, 1.9, 3.4, 3.5]
bar = np.rint(foo).astype(int)
print(bar)
```

Which results in:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```